# Laravel Validator

Tags: laravel-4, validation

I have the following rule in the validator:

```
'keywords' => 'array|required' 
'date_intervals' => 'array|required'
```

The array needs to be populated with at minimum 1 element (should not be empty).
Is there an existing rule to achieve this, or is it required that I write a custom rule for it?

Does `min:1` work with array validation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'd be better counting the array elements and then passing the count for validation.

```
$count = count(Input::get('keywords'));
$input = ['keywords' => Input::get('keywords'),'count' => $count];
$rules = ['keywords' => 'required|array', 'count' => 'min:1'];
```